# How to publish in MavenCentral a build variant different than "release"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nexus

I'm trying to publish a library in MavenCentral. So I'm following [this Chris Banes post](http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html)

The task `uploadArchives` compiles and uploads the `release` version of my library, is there some way of modify the build variant that is uploaded?

I'd like to have two variants `release` and `mavenRelease` with minor config changes. And upload the second when running uploadArchives

Comment: The blog post is about Gradle and NOT about Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure [Library Publication](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication) directly from the android-gradle plugin.

To publish only the `debug` build variant :

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "debug"
}
```

In your case, for your `mavenRelease` build variant :

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "mavenRelease"
}
```

Note that if you add product flavors to your project, you should specify the full name such as :

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "flavor1Debug"
}
```

If you want to publish all variant : `debug`, `release` and `mavenRelease`, use `publishNonDefault true` :

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```